# How to simulate multiplication by addition java

Tags: java, simulate

I need to simulate multiplication by addition by not using the operator of multiplication such as **asterisk** This is my code trial code but seems not working :(

```
while (sum < a + b) { 
sum += a; 
} 

System.out.println (a+" x "+b+" is "+sum); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Looks like a homework.

Comment: @DiogoSantana Homework questions are not prohibited or even discouraged, and haven't been for quite a while. This is, however, a question that doesn't show any research effort, so downvoting is appropriate for that reason.

Comment: Please write out what 5 x 4 is by using addition in your question. Show us what that looks like, and then point out where in your code that is replicated.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Yes, thanks. That's what I ment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have:

```
sum = 0;
while (sum < a + b) { 
    sum += a; 
}
```

will only add `a` to the sum until the sum becomes `a + b`. You would need to use `a * b` in the `while` loop in that case but, as stated, you're not allowed to.

---

Since multiplication is just repeated addition, you can do it with the following (pseudo-) code:

```
a = 5; b = 4

product = 0
acopy = a
while acopy > 0:
    product = product + b
    acopy = acopy - 1
```

That's the basic idea though it has a rather nasty bug for negative numbers.

If you want to handle that as well, you'd need something like:

```
product = 0
acopy = a
while acopy < 0:
    product = product - b
    acopy = acopy + 1
while acopy > 0:
    product = product + b
    acopy = acopy - 1
```

Only *one* of those `while` loops will run, depending on whether `a` is negative or positive (if it's zero, neither will run).

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I've got a problem in System.out.println (a+" x "+b+" is "+sum); the **a** always appear as 0.

Comment: Is this the same as simulating division by subtraction?

Comment: @DummyAccount: yes, it's destructive to `a`. I've changed the code to fix this, just use `acopy` so that `a` is left untouched. And yes, it's similar to division as repeated subtraction.

Comment: Thank you. Is this the condition in division by subtraction? int quotient = 0; 
while (a > b) { 
quotient = quotient + b; 
 a = a - b;
 }

Comment: @Dummy, that should probably be another question but you only add _one_ to `quotient`, use `>=` rather than `>`, and fix for handling negatives as well.